# Automatic URL rewrite after deleting a product

Tags: magento-1.7, url, url-rewrite, product-urls

Is there any way in magento to make an automatic url rewrite to the category of the product, after deleting that product?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try `reindexing`

goto terminal `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/shell`
then type

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php   indexer.php reindexall
```

OR

you can do it from the backend

```
system->indexmanagement
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried reindexing that only makes an url rewrite if the url of the product changes.